# Como somar valores no sql na coluna

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho o seguinte codigo sql:

```
 select PS.PatSldBemValResidAnt
       ,PS.PatSldBemValDepAcum 
       ,Sum(PS.PatSldBemValDep)   PatSldBemValDep
       ,Sum(PS.PatSldBemValResid) PatSldBemValResid       
  from  Pat_Saldo_Bem as PS With(Nolock)
  where PS.EmpCod          LIKE '%01.14%'
    and PS.PatBemCodRed       = '0000351'
    and ((PS.PatSldBemAnoMes >= '201807')
    and (PS.PatSldBemAnoMes  <= '201810'))
 group by PS.PatSldBemValResidAnt, PS.PatSldBemValDepAcum, PS.PatSldBemValDep
```

Como que eu faço para ele me dar o resultado da soma da coluna `Patsaldobem`, junto com o valor mais alto da `PatSaldoDepAcum`?

Segue a imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de mostrar o total da coluna `PatSaldoBemValDep` que é a soma dos valores `187.37+187.37+187.37`

Comment: Sugiro que, considerando-se os dados que constam na figura, você nos informe como deve ser o resultado. Por exemplo: (1) o que fazer com as colunas `PatSldBemValResidAnt` e `PatSldBemValResid`? (2) os valores devem ser agrupados pela coluna `PatBemCodRed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim

```
 Select Max(PS.PatSldBemValDepAcum)
       ,Sum(PS.PatSldBemValDep) PatSldBemValDep
  From  Pat_Saldo_Bem  as PS With(Nolock)
  Where PS.EmpCod LIKE '%01.14%'
    And PS.PatBemCodRed = '0000351'
    And ((PS.PatSldBemAnoMes >= '201807')
    And (PS.PatSldBemAnoMes <= '201810'))
```

O `MAX(campo)` vai resultar o maior valor existente na coluna, se quiser o menor valor você pode usar o `MIN(campo)`.

Comment: sim mas eu preciso somar tbm a coluna PatSaldoBemValDep tem que dar 544,11 o total

Comment: Certo, mas na minha resposta eu informei ali o campo `,Sum(PS.PatSidBemValDep) PatSldBemValDep`... Você esta dizendo que minha resposta está errada ou apenas faltando o campo?

Comment: Ajustei o sql, eu tinha coloca o nome dos fields errado.

Comment: Ele tinha que somar os valores 181.37 os 3

Comment: Então me diga... Está somando errado? Não está somando? O que está errado no meu exemplo?

Comment: Não está errado. Ele tem que só somar os 3 valores 181.37

Comment: 181.37+181.37+181.37

Comment: Carinha, edite sua pergunta então e explique corretamente o que deseja. O exemplo que lhe dei é para resultar algo +/- assim `PatSldBemValDepAcum: 21492,55` e `PatSldBemValDep = 544,11`, isso de acordo com a imagem que você nos deu. Explique também qual é o resultado que você quer e quais os campos que deverão ser resultados.

Comment: o PatSldBemValDep = 544,11 não deu este resultado

Comment: já editei a pergunta

Comment: deu certo só foi tirar o group by. vlw pela ajuda

Comment: Opa, que bom carinha, só preste mais atenção ao analisar os scripts!